# Android Studio. Создание интерактивной таблицы со сложным заголовком и различным содержимым

Tags: android

Хочу создать таблицу. Она должна быть интерактивной, то есть реагировать на нажатия по ее элементам. У нее должен быть сложный заголовок, типа такого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заполняться таблица будет динамически текстовыми данными из объекта и картинками из ресурсов. Т.к. таблица достаточно большая и не поместится на экране, она должна прокручиваться по горизонтали и вертикали.
Как лучше это реализовать? Пока я склоняюсь к HorisontalScrollView c вложенным TableLayout, но застрял уже на создании заголовка, не говоря уже про ожидающий меня ад при наполнении таблицы содержимым:)
Возможно есть более удобный способ сделать это?

Comment: проще использовать одну из [готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+table&type=)